# How to leave project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I can not find a way to leave the project, the owner of which is not me. Any attempts to do this through the IAM lead to nothing. I want the project to stop showing up in my account.

Comment: Did you managed to do this without contacting the project Owner ?

Answer (score 10):

A member of the project with the permission `resourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy` is required to add/remove/update IAM policies on the project. The IAM role `roles/owner`, contains this permission.

The member with this permission is the only member that will be able to remove you from the project typically this is the "Project Owner". Unless your membership is being granted via a Google Group / Google Apps domain that you belong to.

If your Google account is added directly, the "Project Owner" can remove you by:

1. Accessing the project
2. Navigating to "IAM & Admin"
3. Selecting your Google account email from the Members list
4. Selecting "Remove"

If your access is granted via a Google Group / Google Apps domain, you will need to remove yourself from those entities.

Currently, the project will continue to appear in your Project Selection window until you are removed.

Comment: Henry thanks for clarifying.  I was just running into this bug. That is horrible design. I'm not in touch with the project owner anymore, how do I remove my account from the project regardless?

Comment: I have same issue with @Darian311, I'm no longer in touch with the project owner and the project still on my console. Also when I try create new one, it says quota exceed. Just submitted ticket to Google now.

Comment: **TLDR:** you can't leave a project.