# Remove project from my Google Cloud account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions

There is a project for which my Google account was given access when I was working for a company as a developer. After I terminated my contract with the company, they probably forgot to revoke the access I had to the project. As such, the project of that company constantly pops-up on the top list of my Google Cloud Platform.

I am trying to remove it from my account but I can not. Do you know if there is any way to do that?

Bellow I have pictures where the project pops-up.

[image: Select project page]

[image: Manage resources page]

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588640/how-do-i-remove-myself-from-a-project-in-the-google-developer-console

Comment: Your member ID (email address) is present to the other Project's IAM. Someone with Project level privileges to IAM will need to remove your member ID from that project's IAM. There is nothing that you can do other than to notify them.

Answer (score 2):

Here I guess you hold an **Editor** position within the project.

[UPDATE]
Only the owner can delete the project. However other **primitive-lower-level roles** can ask the owner to remove their access.
[/UPDATE]

if you are not the owner of the project, you can't get removed at once.
Please ask your previous company to remove your access permission to this project. As I know so far, Lower-level roles(even **Editors**) cannot leave the project without any action from the owner.

And refer [this](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles) to learn about user roles in a Google Cloud Project.

Google's **Cloud IAM** feature manages all the access levels as specified by the project owner or high-level roles.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you are not the owner of the project you cannot revoke your access

refer to these answers:

https://serverfault.com/a/829309/487865

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44699707/8951071